# Gunicorn flask error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

First off this is not like the typical relative importation error in python so that should be noted. Basically I have deployed my flask app to heroku using gunicorn and the app shows the Application error.
During the development stage everything works but it crashes on deployment.
Upon looking through the heroku logs I see

```
from .config.config import Config
2019-11-17T22:42:23.881100+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

using config instead of .config would obviously solve the problem but then i get importerror during the development stage. I should note that I get multiple errors for all the packages imported this way.
This is going to be a big project and I cant keep changing the package import method everytime. I have checked every flask deployment tutorial but some reason everyone uses one in their examples

Anyways my file structure is

[image]

App.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_heroku import Heroku
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .config.config import Config
from .routes.main import main_blueprint
from flask_login import LoginManager
from  flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
app = Flask(__name__)
# set config for app
app.config.from_object(Config)

# set the 3rd party libraries
heroku = Heroku(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
cors = CORS(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
#
from .models.user import Users

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
print("tables created")
#register blueprinnt
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Procfile

```
  web: gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: try `from config.config import Config` instead of `from .config.config import Config`.

Comment: like i said that works in production but if I want to run it in development, i would get import error

Comment: assuming in local u use command `python app.py` to run your app, not able to see why you will get import errors for `from config.config import Config`?

Comment: i was having same problem. I removed `__init__.py` file from root & used absolute import, i.e. `from config.config import Config`